# How to store and retrieve JSON data using Redis in Python

Tags: python, redis, redis-py

I want to store and retrieve large JSON data with Redis in python.

Example
If user search in grocery items and he typed 'abc'. I want retrieve all the records that contains 'abc' i.e. abc1, abc2 and abc3 etc.

Objects that I want to store in Redis i.e.

**Object 1**

```
key = "abc1"
value = {
         "term":"abc1",
         "type":"grocery"
        }
```

**Object 2.**

```
key = "abc2"
value = {
         "term":"abc2",
         "type":"grocery"
        }
```

Objects that I want to retrieve if he type 'abc' i.e.

**Response**

```
data = [
        {
         "term":"abc1",
         "type":"grocery"
        },
       {
         "term":"abc2",
         "type":"grocery"
        }
]
```

**Note**
The recommended method should be fast.

Comment: There are a lot of info here https://github.com/redis/redis-py

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.